# terraform managed_policy_arns issue with aws_iam_role

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

The below code removes the iam policy eks-fargate-logging-policy. What is the right way to define aws managed and customer managed policies together?

```
    resource "aws_iam_policy" "eks-fargate-logging-policy" {
  name        = "eks-fargate-logging-policy"
  description = "Policy for fargate logs to cloudwatch"

  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = [
          "logs:CreateLogStream",
          "logs:CreateLogGroup",
          "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
          "logs:PutLogEvents"
        ]
        Effect   = "Allow"
        Resource = "*"
      },
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "fargate_pod_execution_role" {
  name                  = "${var.eks_cluster_name}-eks-fargate-pod-execution-role"
  assume_role_policy    = data.aws_iam_policy_document.fargate_assume_role.json

#Here's the issue
  managed_policy_arns   = [aws_iam_policy.eks-fargate-logging-policy.arn,"arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSFargatePodExecutionRolePolicy"]
  force_detach_policies = true
}
```

Comment: Terraform removes resources when you change some immutable aspect about them. What does the plan say is forcing the recreation?

Comment: Is your customer managed policy is a typo or obfuscated as "aws", dont see account number in ARN ? arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSFargatePodExecutionRolePolicy, probably a copy paste issue from a AWS managed policy ARN

Comment: @omuthu this policy is amazon managed, account is not needed. No issues with the  arn -arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSFargatePodExecutionRolePolicy

Answer (score 1):

I don't see this issue anymore. Looks like it works as expected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).